# wpf Image resources and visual studio 2010 resource editor

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, image, resource-editor

My motivation for this question is really just to specify an image to be used in a user control via a dependency property for ImageSource. I'm hitting some pain points involving the management, access, and unit testing for this.

- Is the resource editor a good tool to use to maintain images for the application?
- What is the best way to translate the Bitmap from the editor to an ImageSource?
- How can I grab the resource Filename from the editor?

Comment: What do you mean by maintaining images using the resource editor?

Comment: I mean adding image(s) to the resource designer and then finding them there when needed. Or if that's a bad idea then what is a better one for a non-trivial app that may have images in multiple assemblies. Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the resource editor is not a good tool for this.

In a WPF application the best way is to put all of your images in an "Images" directory and mark each one as a "Resource".  Then you can reference them directly in Image controls and elsewhere.

Here are the precise steps:

- Crop and otherwise adjust your images using your favorite bitmap editing program (Paint.NET, Photoshop, etc)
- Save them as .png files (or .jpg or .gif if you prefer)
- Create an "Images" folder inside your Visual Studio solution (or multiple folders, however you want to organize it)
- Drag the images from your hard disk into your "Images" folder (or right-click the project, select New -> Existing Item and select the images)

Now you can reference your images easily in XAML:

```
<Image Source="Images/MyImage.png" />
```

Or in code:

```
var source = (BitmapSource)Application.LoadComponent(
               new Uri("Images/MyImage.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

You can also reference images in external assemblies:

```
<Image Source="ReferencedAssembly;v1.0.0.1;component/Images/MyImage.png" />
```

Which in code would be:

```
var source = (BitmapSource)Application.LoadComponent(
               new Uri("ReferencedAssembly;v1.0.0.1;component/Images/MyImage.png",
                 UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Perfect! Two questions - (1) any practical advantage to having the build action be 'Content' over 'Resource'? (2) Would the code to get at in a referenced assembly, just be 'Application.LoadComponent("ReferencedAssembly;v1.0.0.1; component/Images/MyImage.png") as BitmapSource;'? Do you know of any helper code to get that syntax (sorry, three questions)?? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like Application.LoadComponent takes a Uri (not a string)

Comment: Thanks.  Somehow I always forget the "new Uri(..., UriKind.Relative)" until the compiler points out the error of my ways.  I have corrected the answer.

Comment: "Resource" adds the file to your .exe or .dll.  "Content" stores the file as a separate file in your output directory.  It is usually easier to deploy a single .exe file, but if you have huge image files or hundreds of them it may be better to use Content instead.

Comment: Great answer!  Super clear writing.  Mad thumbs.  I used this question to write source code just now.  One thing I noticed: If your resource lies in a diff assembly (another class library DLL), you might want to use this URI format: "pack://application:,,,/YourAssemblyName;component/Images/MyImage.png"  I am still confused when to use Images folder + Build Action=Resource vs Resource Editor.  Also, is Build Action=Resource and Build Action=Embedded Resource the same here because the resource is binary data?